# Undefined index: category_icon_code in line 257

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

Hello I am getting Notice Undefined index: in line number 257.
Please help. 
Here is code for line number 257.

```
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
            while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                $my_query->the_post();
                global $postID;
                $current++;
                $category = get_the_category();
                $tag = get_cat_ID( $category[0]->name );
                $tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
                if (isset($tag_extra_fields[$tag])) {
                    $category_icon_code = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_code']; 
                    $category_icon_color = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_color'];
                    $your_image_url = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['your_image_url'];
                }
                if (empty($category_icon_code) || empty($category_icon_color) || empty($your_image_url)) {

                        $tag = $category[0]->category_parent;

                        $tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
                        if (isset($tag_extra_fields[$tag])) {
                            if (empty($category_icon_code)){
                                $category_icon_code = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_code'];
                            }
                            if (empty($category_icon_color)){
                                $category_icon_color = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_color'];
                            }
                            if (empty($your_image_url)){
                                $your_image_url = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['your_image_url'];
                            }
                        }

                    }
            ?>
```

I am getting undefined index for these.

```
$category_icon_code
$category_icon_color
$your_image_url
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set these `variables` as default empty before the `while` loop like:

```
$category_icon_code = "";
$category_icon_color = "";
$your_image_url = "";
```

Comment: Already done this, but still seen this issue. Notice is not regarding undefined Variables, Notice is regarding undefined index.

Comment: $my_query = new wp_query( $args ); this is line 257?? @MrShabir